# How to show data in form to update new data to DB?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update the data in the DB through the form on my page, I'm done till viewing each data. But I get an error when I go to update.php. It shows the PHP code in the form input instead of value.

[image: example of error]

After I replace that PHP code in the input box on the form with new data, data was successfully updated. I only have a problem in viewing the data on the form.

Here is my update.php

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || (trim($_SESSION['password']) == '')) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>EXA_mySQL</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">function checkinput() { 
    var id_mesin = document.getElementById('id_mesin').value;  
    if(!id_mesin.match(/\S/)) {
        alert ('Please enter Machine ID');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$id_mesin = $_POST['id_mesin'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM asset WHERE id_mesin ='$id_mesin'");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<table width="733" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form_insert" method="post" action="update_ac.php" onSubmit="return checkinput(this)">
<table width="100%" height="398" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="9" align="center"><strong>Update Data Into EXA_mySQL Database </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="106">MACHINE ID</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td colspan="3"><input name="id_mesin" type="text" id="id_mesin" value="<? echo $rows['$id_mesin']; ?>"></td>
<td colspan="2">BRAND</td>
<td width="9">:</td>
<td width="164"><select name="jenama">
  <option value=" " selected>Please select :</option>
  <option value="SHARP">SHARP</option>
  <option value="TOSHIBA">TOSHIBA</option>
  <option value="CANON">CANON</option>
  <option value="SAMSUNG">SAMSUNG</option>
  <option value="MEXTEC">MEXTEC</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>MODEL</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="3"><input name="model" type="text" id="model" value="<? echo $rows['model']; ?>"></td>
<td colspan="2">METER START</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="meter_awal" type="text" id="meter_awal" value="<? echo $rows['meter_awal']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SERIAL NO</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="3">MACHINE</td>
<td colspan="2">FEEDER</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>FINISHER</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="3"><input name="siri_mesin" type="text" id="siri_mesin" value="<? echo $rows['siri_mesin']; ?>"></td>
  <td colspan="3"><input name="siri_feeder" type="text" id="siri_feeder" value="<? echo $rows['siri_feeder']; ?>"></td>
  <td><input name="siri_finisher" type="text" id="siri_finisher" value="<? echo $rows['siri_finisher']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STOCK IN</td>
<td>:</td>
<td width="58">DATE</td>
<td width="8">:</td>
<td width="220"><input type="text" name="stok_in" id="stok_in" value="<? echo $rows['stok_in']; ?>"></td>
<td colspan="2">D.O NO </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="in_do" id="in_do" value="<? echo $rows['in_do']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LOCATION</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="3"><select name="lokasi">
  <option value="Location not set" selected>Please select :</option>
  <option value="HQ WAREHOUSE">HQ WAREHOUSE</option>
  <option value="CHENDERING WAREHOUSE">CHENDERING WAREHOUSE</option>
</select></td>
<td colspan="2">J.S.O</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="js_order" id="js_order" value="<? echo $rows['js_order']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STOCK OUT</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>DATE</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="stok_out" id="stok_out" value="<? echo $rows['stok_out']; ?>"></td>
<td colspan="2">D.O NO </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="out_do" id="out_do" value="<? echo $rows['out_do']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CUSTOMER</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="7"><input name="pelangan" type="text" id="pelangan" size="90" value="<? echo $rows['pelangan']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ADDRESS</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td colspan="7"><textarea name="pelangan_alamat" cols="69" id="pelangan_alamat" value="<? echo $rows['pelangan_alamat']; ?>"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>CONTACT PERSON</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="4"><input name="pelangan_person" type="text" id="pelangan_person" size="50" value="<? echo $rows['pelangan_person']; ?>"></td>
<td width="109">NO TEL/HP</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pelangan_no" id="pelangan_no" value="<? echo $rows['pelangan_no']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>TECHNICIAN INCHARGE</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td colspan="4"><input name="tech" type="text" id="tech" size="50" value="<? echo $rows['tech']; ?>"></td>
  <td>NO TEL/HP</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="tech_no" id="tech_no" value="<? echo $rows['tech_no']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>STATUS</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td colspan="3"><select name="status">
    <option value="Status not set" selected>Please select :</option>
    <option value="ORDER PURCHASE">ORDER PURCHASE</option>
    <option value="RENTAL">RENTAL</option>
    <option value="HIRE PURCHASE">HIRE PURCHASE</option>
  </select></td>
  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3" align="left"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying with few other codes for

```
value="<? echo $rows['pelangan_person']; ?>"
```

but they're still not working. I can't find the correct code for the value to show 'the value', not the code. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

here is my data_view page with button to update data.

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || (trim($_SESSION['password']) == '')) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>EXA_mySQL</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$id_mesin = $_POST['id_mesin'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM asset WHERE id_mesin ='$id_mesin'");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>No Tag</th>
<th>Jenama</th>
<th>Model</th>
<th>No Siri</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Pemilik</th>
<th>Lokasi</th>
<th>Rekod</th>
<th>Update</th>

</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {


"<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id_mesin'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['jenama'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['siri_mesin'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['pemilik'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lokasi'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['rekod'] . "</td>";
//echo "<td><a href='update.php?id=" . $row['id_mesin'] . "'>update</a></td>";
echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<td> <input type='hidden' value='" . $row["id_mesin"] . "' name='id_mesin'>";
echo "<input type='submit' onclick='myPopup2()' value='Update'></td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</tr>";

  }
echo "<a href='exa_mysql.php'>Back to EXA_mySQL</a>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myPopup2() {
window.open( "http://localhost/update.php", "myWindow", 
"status = 1,location=no,toolbar=no, resizable=no, height = 600, width = 900" )
}

</script>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

could the cause is from data_view page that didn't sent any value to update.php?

here is my table data structure :

```
 CREATE TABLE `asset` (
 `id_mesin` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `jenama` text NOT NULL,
 `model` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `siri_mesin` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `siri_feeder` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `siri_finisher` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `meter_awal` int(15) NOT NULL,
 `lokasi` text NOT NULL,
 `status` text NOT NULL,
 `stok_in` date NOT NULL,
 `stok_out` date NOT NULL,
 `in_do` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `out_do` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `pelangan` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `pelangan_alamat` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
 `pelangan_person` text NOT NULL,
 `pelangan_no` int(15) NOT NULL,
 `js_order` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `tech` text NOT NULL,
 `tech_no` int(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_mesin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Try this: `<?php IF (!empty($rows['$id_mesin'])) { echo $rows['pelangan_person']}; ?>`

Comment: have you tried using the proper <?php  ?> tags?

Comment: @Mr.Radical, using `<?php IF (!empty($rows['$id_mesin'])) { echo $rows['pelangan_person']}; ?>` in dreamviewer show syntax error. and thanks to @Alison R. for fixing my grammar. :)

Comment: my mistake: `<?php IF (!empty($rows['pelangan_person'])) { echo $rows['pelangan_person']};`

Comment: @newbie have you viewed my answer below?

Comment: @Mr.Radical, yes. i have viewed and study your answer. if the value not empty then show the value. i'm tried but its seem didn't catch any value from DB.

Comment: @Mr.Radical, i'm making some change to my data_view page.
`echo "<form action='update.php?id=".$row['id_mesin']."' method='post'>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='" . $row["id_mesin"] . "' name='id_mesin'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Update'></td>";
echo "</form>";` and its show
<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-w-T1PCus_QU/Uv36nCWnYEI/AAAAAAAAABc/euZBHhY5UT4/w309-h91-no/update_form2.JPG"> using code `value="<?php IF(!empty($model)) {echo $model;} else {echo "no data receive";}; ?>"` in update.php

Comment: @newbie so you tried my whole code what exact error message did you get. I got a page with all the fields without any problem. Only thing missing is the table structure so I received so mysql error related to that.

Comment: @Mr.Radical,i try use the whole code. and it give me result as this image <image src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-6JLjEFsKkrQ/Uv4La6SK-gI/AAAAAAAAACY/5INWQL4SWAE/w1040-h573-no/update_form3.JPG">

Comment: @Mr.Radical, so then, if i change `$id_mesin = isset($_POST['id_mesin']);` to `$id_mesin = $_POST['id_mesin'];` its only retrieve value from column `id_mesin` only. here is the picture. <image src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-A3_nu_KOKDY/Uv4NIcGQQ_I/AAAAAAAAACw/XGaRYaeKY9k/w1044-h557-no/update_form4.JPG">

Comment: @newbie do you get transferred to login.php if you open the page. if so it is because you are not loged in yet. The session wasn't started yet. You can check this by commenting out this test. Place `/*` before this test and `*/` after this test. To be sure this the everything in between the first php tags. Alternatively you could first login then go to this page like you would on every other site.

Comment: @Mr.Radical, i have no problem with session. if i'm not login, i cant open any page.

Comment: @newbie does the location of your browser get changed to login.php? With regard to your edit how does `$_POST['id_mesin']` get set?

Comment: @Mr.Radical, my page address location didn't change to login.php. u can check my link in comment above to see the screenshot image. and about `$_POST['id_mesin'] get set, i'm not sure. if you check 2 image of screenshot above, you may know how my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || (trim($_SESSION['password']) == '')) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EXA_mySQL</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body,td,th {
                font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">function checkinput() {
                var id_mesin = document.getElementById('id_mesin').value;
                if (!id_mesin.match(/\S/)) {
                    alert('Please enter Machine ID');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        </script>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id_mesin = isset($_POST['id_mesin']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM asset WHERE id_mesin ='" . $id_mesin . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
        <table width="733" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <td><form name="form_insert" method="post" action="update_ac.php" onSubmit="return checkinput(this);">
                        <table width="100%" height="398" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="9" align="center"><strong>Update Data Into EXA_mySQL Database </strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="106">MACHINE ID</td>
                                <td width="6">:</td>
                                <td colspan="3"><input name="id_mesin" type="text" id="id_mesin" value="<?php
        IF (!empty($id_mesin)) {
            echo $id_mesin;
        };
?>"></td>
                                <td colspan="2">BRAND</td>
                                <td width="9">:</td>
                                <td width="164"><select name="jenama">
                                        <option value="SHARP" <?php IF ($rows['jenama'] === "SHARP") echo 'selected=selected'; ?> >SHARP</option>
                                        <option value="TOSHIBA" <?php IF ($rows['jenama'] === "TOSHIBA") echo 'selected=selected'; ?> >TOSHIBA</option>
                                        <option value="CANON" <?php IF ($rows['jenama'] === "CANON") echo 'selected=selected'; ?> >CANON</option>
                                        <option value="SAMSUNG" <?php IF ($rows['jenama'] === "SAMSUNG") echo 'selected=selected'; ?> >SAMSUNG</option>
                                        <option value="MEXTEC" <?php IF ($rows['jenama'] === "MEXTEX") echo 'selected=selected'; ?>>MEXTEC</option>
                                    </select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>MODEL</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td colspan="3"><input name="model" type="text" id="model" value="<?php
                                    IF (!empty($rows['model'])) {
                                        echo $rows['model'];
                                    };
                                    ?>"></td>
                                <td colspan="2">METER START</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input name="meter_awal" type="text" id="meter_awal" value="<?php
                                    IF (!empty($rows['meter_awal'])) {
                                        echo $rows['meter_awal'];
                                    };
                                    ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>SERIAL NO</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td colspan="3">MACHINE</td>
                                <td colspan="2">FEEDER</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>FINISHER</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td colspan="3"><input name="siri_mesin" type="text" id="siri_mesin" value="<?php
                                                       IF (!empty($rows['siri_mesin'])) {
                                                           echo $rows['siri_mesin'];
                                                       };
                                                       ?>"></td>
                                <td colspan="3"><input name="siri_feeder" type="text" id="siri_feeder" value="<?php
                                    IF (!empty($rows['siri_feeder'])) {
                                        echo $rows['siri_feeder'];
                                    };
                                                       ?>"></td>
                                <td><input name="siri_finisher" type="text" id="siri_finisher" value="<?php
                                    IF (!empty($rows['siri_finisher'])) {
                                        echo $rows['siri_finisher'];
                                    };
                                                       ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>STOCK IN</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td width="58">DATE</td>
                                <td width="8">:</td>
                                <td width="220"><input type="text" name="stok_in" id="stok_in" value="<?php
                                                       IF (!empty($rows['stok_in'])) {
                                                           echo $rows['stok_in'];
                                                       };
                                                       ?>"></td>
                                <td colspan="2">D.O NO </td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="in_do" id="in_do" value="<?php
                                                       IF (!empty($rows['in_do'])) {
                                                           echo $rows['in_do'];
                                                       };
                                                       ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>LOCATION</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td colspan="3"><select name="lokasi">
                                        <option value="HQ WAREHOUSE" <?php IF ($rows['lokasi'] === "HQ WAREHOUSE") echo 'selected=selected'; ?> >HQ WAREHOUSE</option>
                                        <option value="CHENDERING WAREHOUSE" <?php IF ($rows['lokasi'] === "CHENDERING WAREHOUSE") echo 'selected=selected'; ?> >CHENDERING WAREHOUSE</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                <td colspan="2">J.S.O</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="js_order" id="js_order" value="<?php
                                    IF (!empty($rows['js_order'])) {
                                        echo $rows['js_order'];
                                    };
                                    ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>STOCK OUT</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td>DATE</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="stok_out" id="stok_out" value="<?php
                                    IF (!empty($rows['stok_out'])) {
                                        echo $rows['stok_out'];
                                    };
                                    ?>"></td>
                                <td colspan="2">D.O NO </td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="out_do" id="out_do" value="<?php
                                    IF (!empty($rows['out_do'])) {
                                        echo $rows['out_do'];
                                    };
                                    ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>CUSTOMER</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td colspan="7"><input name="pelangan" type="text" id="pelangan" size="90" value="<?php
                                                       IF (!empty($rows['pelangan'])) {
                                                           echo $rows['pelangan'];
                                                       };
                                    ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>ADDRESS</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                            <div> <td colspan="7"><textarea name="pelangan_alamat" cols="69" id="pelangan_alamat" ><?php IF (!empty($rows['pelangan_alamat'])) {echo $rows['pelangan_alamat'];}; ?></textarea></div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>CONTACT PERSON</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td colspan="4"><input name="pelangan_person" type="text" id="pelangan_person" size="50" value="<?php
                                                       IF (!empty($rows['pelangan_person'])) {
                                                           echo $rows['pelangan_person'];
                                                       };
                                    ?>"></td>
                                <td width="109">NO TEL/HP</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="pelangan_no" id="pelangan_no" value="<?php
                                                       IF (!empty($rows['pelangan_no'])) {
                                                           echo $rows['pelangan_no'];
                                                       };
                                    ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>TECHNICIAN INCHARGE</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td colspan="4"><input name="tech" type="text" id="tech" size="50" value="<?php
                                                       IF (!empty($rows['stok_out'])) {
                                                           echo $rows['tech'];
                                                       };
                                    ?>"></td>
                                <td>NO TEL/HP</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="tech_no" id="tech_no" value="<?php
                                                       IF (!empty($rows['tech_no'])) {
                                                           echo $rows['tech_no'];
                                                       };
                                    ?>"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>STATUS</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td colspan="3"><select name="status">
                                        <option value="ORDER PURCHASE" <?php IF ($rows['status'] === "ORDER PURCHASE") echo 'selected=selected'; ?> >ORDER PURCHASE</option>
                                        <option value="RENTAL" <?php IF ($rows['status'] === "RENTAL") echo 'selected=selected'; ?> >RENTAL</option>
                                        <option value="HIRE PURCHASE" <?php IF ($rows['status'] === "HIRE PURCHASE") echo 'selected=selected'; ?>>HIRE PURCHASE</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td colspan="3" align="left"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Before you can test it fill in the username, password, etc.

Comment: i'm notice that you made few change in my code at query `WHERE id_mesin = '".$id_mesin."'"` and `value="<?php IF(!empty($id_mesin)) {echo $id_mesin;} ; ?>"` but its only show blank from.

Comment: i try this code `value="<?php IF(!empty($id_mesin)) {echo $id_mesin;} ; ?>"` and `value="<?php IF(!empty($rows['model'])) {echo $rows['model'];}; ?>"` both only show blank form.

Comment: @newbie try the code above and let me know what error message you receive. Change `$id_mesin = $_POST['id_mesin'];` into a `$id_mesin = 1;` or another value you know will be in the database.

Comment: BTW why not save `$id_mesin` in the session? That is if `$id_mesin` stays the same during the session.

Comment: when i'm using your code `$id_mesin = isset($_POST['id_mesin']);`. only the MACHINE ID show the value = 1. same output with code `$id_mesin = 1;`.

Comment: @newbie Change `$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);` into `$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: @newbie updated my code. I think the problem is caused by using both the mysql_ and mysqli_ library.

Comment: Great. its working now. thanks a lot @Mr. Radical. But still got error in displaying value for textarea and select form.

Comment: Could you place the table structure of your table asset? In the mysql command line type `SHOW CREATE TABLE asset;` And give some sample data for the table.

Comment: In a nutshell you need to do a test if the value is selected in the database. Something like `<?php IF ($_POST['jenama'] = "SHARP") echo '"selected=selected"'; ?>` in the input tag.

Comment: W.r.t. texterea `<textarea name="pelangan_alamat" cols="69" id="pelangan_alamat" ><?php IF (!empty($rows['pelangan_alamat'])) { echo $rows['pelangan_alamat'];}; ?></textarea>`. The trick is to place your database output in between textarea tags.

Comment: as your request, i've adding my asset table data structure. for display value in textarea is done. but for showing selected value still wont work.

Comment: i'm using code `<?php IF ($_POST['jenama'] = "SHARP") echo '"selected=selected"'; ?>` then its show value only `"SHARP"`, then i'm trying to putting all the code to all value. then its show the last value for all data. i'm sorry, i'm already accept your answer but still asking you for the help.

Comment: @newbie see my update. And please work on you mysql table (e.g. change id_mesin varchar into id_mesin int auto_increment primary key; multiple text fields should be changed into varchar, because VARCHAR is smaller than text and not the other way around. ). It will take too long for me to make all the alterations.

Comment: thanks again. and for your advise, my id_mesin contain 'tetx/number/symbol', so i cant set id_mesin as int. also id_mesin cant have same value. thats why i choose id_mesin as PK. and about multiple text fields, i thought text is smaller than varchar. nice info. :) really thanks to you man.

Comment: Your query will be faster if you would use an int as ID field. You can still do the search with whatever you like. Furthermore, you could look at database design and normalization. E.g. jenema is the name of the manufacture you could create a separate table for jenema `CREATE TABLE jenama (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(30));` and add an jenema_id int field in table asset instead of the typing the name you put a 1. This avoids problems when you misspell a SHAR instead of SHARP.  Then to retieve`SELECT * FROM asset JOIN jenama ON asset.jenema_id = jenama.id WHERE id_mesin = 1;`

Comment: noted. i can see, from separating table is for easy to manage and manipulate. hope i can use this in future on new project. this project  only a small scale. to make it a big scale, sure need a lot of time. then, that day is the time to apply all of your suggestion. wish me luck.. :P

and, thanks bro.

Comment: @newbie success with your project. Glad to been of help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to open php code with  `<?php` instead of just `<?` 
try this please :

```
value="<?php echo $rows['pelangan_person']; ?>"
```

Comment: @newbie the code is correct , if it's not showing you that code on the input like in the image you post . then the value of what you trying to show is empty

Comment: some times short tags are not enabled. see `phpinfo()` to check this.

Comment: @cipherux ;Il existe des notations raccourcies : <? et ?>, voire la notation ASP <% et %>, mais celles-ci sont déconseillées, car elles peuvent être désactivées dans la configuration du serveur (php.ini ou .htaccess) : la portabilité du code est ainsi réduite.  http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP

Comment: @lmadOS, from your comment. i can see you are saying my update form didn't pick up any value from DB to show OR my previous page didn't post any value to update form. here my submit code from previous page
`echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<td> <input type='hidden' value='" . $row['id_mesin'] . "' name='id_mesin'>";
echo "<input type='submit' onclick='myPopup2()' value='Update'></td>";
echo "</form>";`
could this cause the error?

Comment: @newbie , i think the code wouldn't cause any error

Comment: Include a if statement to check if your variable is empty or not.

Comment: @Mr.Radical, how to using if statement in update form? i'm using if statement on page update_ac.php. and after me rewrite new data, data successfully updated.